# I'm not sure I understand the type definition of the foldl function in haskell

Tags: haskell, types, syntax, signature

When I ask about the foldl type, what I see is this:

```
*Main> :t foldl
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

In this case, what is `t a`?

I guess it means that the function is using a `Foldable` parametrized with `a` but I'm not even really sure about the syntax. For instance, why can't I substitute `t a` with `Foldable a`?

And, bonus question, if I had to define `foldl` myself, I would start with the base case

```
foldl f b [] = []
```

But if the base case takes a list, than it would not make much sense to accept a `Foldable`. What is the "empty Foldable" that I could use as the base case?

Comment: `t` is a "foldable". Most collections are foldable, for example `Foldable []`, so you can perform this on a list, but usually also on `Tree`s, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand what `Foldable` is. What I don't get is the syntax here and how to use Foldable for my custom functions.

Comment: The "empty Foldable" isn't defined for all `Foldable`s; each type with a `Foldable` instance defines its own.

Comment: ... and some instances of `Foldable` don't even admit empty values (cf. [`Data.List.NonEmpty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Foldable` is something called a "typeclass".  Saying `Foldable t =>` declares that `t` must implement the requirements of `Foldable`.  However, `t` remains `t`, and doesn't get collapsed into a reference to a `Foldable` interface like it might in Java.  That's why you can't just have `Foldable a`.

Definitely check out https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html for an explanation of the requirements of `Foldable` and what methods that gets you.

Anyways, if you want to use one of `Foldable`'s methods, then either use a known `Foldable` type like `Set`:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
import Data.Foldable

sumSet :: (Num n) => S.Set n -> n
sumSet ns = foldl' (\ n acc -> n + acc ) 0 ns --make this pointfree if you want
```

Or you can take a type parameter and constrain it to be foldable:

```
sumFld :: (Num n, Foldable f) => f n -> n --different signature
sumFld ns = foldl' (\ n acc -> n + acc ) 0 ns --same implementation!
```

The following prints 6, twice:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print (sumSet $ S.fromList [1, 2, 3]) >> print (sumFld $ S.fromList [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Also note that in Haskell, you can't put different types implementing the same typeclass into the same collection!  This is another big difference from Java which really tripped me up.

Answer (score 6):

I like the other answers, which discuss briefly the distinction between types and classes and so answer the first half of the question in that way. To keep this answer complete, I'll reiterate this very briefly; but see the other answers for longer explanations, since I want to spend the bulk of my time on the second half of the question.

So: `Foldable` is a typeclass (a collection of types). The `t` in the type of `foldl` rangers over types, not collections of types, and this explains why it can't be replaced by `Foldable`.

But I think this is also a very interesting question that the other answers didn't address:

> If I had to define `foldl` myself, I would start with the base case
>
> ```
> foldl f b [] = []
> ```
>
> But if the base case takes a list, than it would not make much sense to accept a `Foldable`.

If you were to define `foldl` yourself, you would be creating an instance of `Foldable` for a *specific type*. Because in the instance you know which specific type is involved, you can write base cases for *that* type and need not know about any other instances of `Foldable`. In the `Foldable` instance for lists:

```
instance Foldable [] where
    foldl f b [] = b
```

...is perfectly well-typed, because we know `t ~ []`. On the other hand, in the instance for another type, we would of course have to use a different base case. For example:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
instance Foldable S.Set where
    foldl f b s | S.null s = b
```

Again, this is okay *inside the `instance` block* because then we have `t ~ S.Set`. We can (and generally have to) write things that only work on `S.Set`s and would not work well with other `Foldable` instances.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
> ```
>
> In this case, what is `t a`?
>
> I guess it means that the function is using a `Foldable` parametrized with `a` [...]

That's exactly right. Note, however, that it is "**a** `Foldable` parameterized with `a`", and not "`Foldable` parametrized with `a`". As [hegel5000's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49037040/2751851) explains, when you write `Foldable t` to the left of `=>`, you are saying something *about* the type (constructor) `t`. Replacing `t a` with `Foldable a` would be a little like putting an adjective where a noun should be.

Moving on to your bonus question: `foldl` happens to be a method of the `Foldable` class. That means you are able to, when writing an instance of `Foldable` for a type, to supply an appropriate definition of `foldl` in which you can make use of the specific features of the type (e.g. that `[]` is a constructor of lists -- see also [Daniel Wagner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49038215/2751851)).

If `foldl` weren't a method of `Foldable`, though, the only things you would be able to use to deal with the `t a` argument when implementing it would be the (other) methods of `Foldable` (`foldr`, `foldMap`, etc.), as you don't know anything else about `t` other than the fact that it has a `Foldable` instance. (Perhaps surprisingly, it is possible to implement `foldl` in such a way. Such an implementation is provided as a default for the `foldl` method in the `Foldable` class, so that you don't have to implement it yourself when writing an instance if you don't consider it necessary.)

Answer (score 2):

In the context `(Foldable t) => ...` the `t` is the foldable type. An example of this could be the list  type `[]`.

Some more concrete types for `foldl` would be

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
```

`Foldable t => ...` can be read as `t` is required to be a `Foldable`. It is not the type constructor `Foldable` applied to the type `t`! Therefore `Foldable t` is not even a type and you can't ever use it on the right hand side of a `=>`.