# Fold type signature with `Foldable` type constraint

Tags: haskell, fold, type-signature

On my `GHCi` `foldr` and `foldl` have this signature:

```
Prelude> :t foldr
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
Prelude> :t foldl
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

What is the difference between the alternative type signature of fold, specifically `t a` part?

```
fr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
fl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Comment: Are you just asking what `t a` means? Do you understand what the `Foldable t =>` part means?

Comment: No, I have no idea.

Comment: Near duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49036437/1126841 asked just yesterday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type class `Foldable` defines a number of functions in addition to `foldl`.

```
class Foldable t where
    foldMap :: Monoid m => t m -> m
    foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
    foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
    -- ...
```

We can define an *instance* of `Foldable` for a type constructor `t` by defining at least `foldMap` or `foldr` for the type. (`foldl` has a default definition in terms of some of the others, so you get it for "free" as long as you supply the minimum definition).

```
instance Foldable [] where
    foldr f b [] = b
    foldr f b (x:xs) = f x : foldr f b xs

instance Foldable Maybe where
    foldr f b Nothing = b
    foldr f b (Just a) = f b a
```

The `t` in the type signature just means that as long as a type constructor has a `Foldable` instance for it defined, you can use `foldl` with a value of the appropriate type. For example:

```
Prelude> foldl (+) 0 [1,2,3]
6
Prelude> foldl (+) 0 []
0
Prelude> foldl (+) 0 Nothing
0
Prelude> foldl (+) 0 (Just 3)
3
```

In the first two cases, we use the `[]` instance because the arguments corresponding to `t a` are lists, meaning `t` is *unified* with `[]`, written `t ~ []`. In the second two, we use the `Maybe` instance because the arguments corresponding to `t a` are `Maybe` values, so `t ~ Maybe`.

Comment: I did not know that you could write type signature for lists like this `[] a` instead of `[a]`. Is this similar to `Foldable`?

Comment: `[a]` is just syntactic sugar for `[] a` (and I think `[]` is special-cased to be a valid name for a type constructor). `Foldable` is just a generalization for the various folds, allowing you to use `foldl` et al. on container types other than lists.